Update mail form required password not name - Laravel Breeze
I want to update the mail user's with password verification and not a name verification, I can't change the form and the method in the controller, I used the profil edit from Laravel Breeze
Model
 protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];

Controller
  public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->user()->fill($request->validated());

        if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
            $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
        }

        $request->user()->save();

        return Redirect::route('dashboard')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
    }

view
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}" class="mt-6 space-y-6">
                            @csrf
                            @method('patch')

                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                                <x-input-label class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                                               for="email" :value="__('New email')"/>
                                <x-text-input id="email" name="email" type="email"
                                              class="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"
                                              :value="old('email', $user->email)" required autocomplete="username"/>
                                <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('email')"/>


                                @if ($user instanceof \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail && ! $user->hasVerifiedEmail())
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="text-sm mt-2 text-gray-800">
                                            {{ __('Your email address is unverified.') }}

                                            <button form="send-verification"
                                                    class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                                {{ __('Click here to re-send the verification email.') }}
                                            </button>
                                        </p>

                                        @if (session('status') === 'verification-link-sent')
                                            <p class="mt-2 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">
                                                {{ __('A new verification link has been sent to your email address.') }}
                                            </p>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                                <x-input-label class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
                                               for="name" :value="__('Name')"/>
                                <x-text-input id="name" name="name" type="text"
                                              class="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"
                                              :value="old('name', $user->name)" required autofocus autocomplete="name"/>
                                <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('name')"/>
                            </div>

I tried to update the form view with a password field instead of the name field and to add this method from the password controller in the edit email controller
   $validated = $request->validateWithBag('updatePassword', [
            'current_password' => ['required', 'current_password'],
            'password' => ['required', Password::defaults(), 'confirmed'],
        ]);

        $request->user()->update([
            'password' => Hash::make($validated['password']),
        ]);


I'm very sorry, but I truly do not understand the question. Can you please rephrase it?
